# The space of loops as a Banach space

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $S$ be the space of all loops in $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. all continuous mappings $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$.  Is there any canonical interpretation of $S$ as a Banach space?  If so, is its dual space easy to define?

Comment: Wouldn't this be $C(\mathbb T)$, continuous functions from the circle into complex numbers. It is a C$^*$-algebra and so a Banach space with dual the space of all Radon measures of $X$, $M(X)$.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for, if you want to make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space of loops in $\mathbb R^2$ is the same as $C(\mathbb T)$, the continuous functions of the circle into the complex numbers. This is a C$^*$-algebra and thus a Banach space.

It is well known that the dual of $C(\mathbb T)$ is $M(\mathbb T)$, the space of all Radon measures of the circle.